# my servo tries to go past its limit and wont stop until i unplug it, and force it into some normal posotion

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, servo, rc

I just bought 4 of these digital tower pro MG996R hi torque 180° servos for my Arduino.
So, I put them into classical sweep test, however after some time. Without any reason it starts rotating clockwise until it reaches its limit, and tries to force itself past it, making weird buzzing noise(probably by the PWM) and consuming a lot of power.
From 4 of them 2 do this and I have not yet tested the other 2, is there any explanation for it/how to fix it

Here is that code:

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>
int pos = 0;

void setup() {myservo.attach(22);}

void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }

  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }

}
```

I tried using some blue tower pro
SG90 microservo and it works just fine.
are there some weird changes between those small blue servos, and other more robust ones, besides`s` power, speed, or voltage?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Unfortunately your question is not about programming, and it might be better suited on another StackExchange site, for example Arduino or Electrical Engineering. If you post your question there, please add more details, specifically how you power the servos.

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware issue rather than a programming issue. That aside, if I remember, hobby servos often can't travel the entire range of the signal, so I suspect 180 is beyond the end of the servo's physical travel range and the sound you hear is gears grinding (skipping) while trying to achieve that position anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao,
You should consult, if available, the servomotor datasheet to check what are the necessary pulse width values to move the shaft to 0° or 180°.

The Arduino Servo library have a minimum and maximum value defined by default, these can be set, for example, using the attach function.
Default values are 544 microseconds and 2400 microseconds.
Minimum and maximum of the attach(pin,min,max) function can also be useful to fine tune the movement of the servos.
An interactive function could be created to more easily tune the servo positioning at its limits.
If there are mechanical limiters in the servos, You should also check if they can be modified and if properly set.

You find an use of minimum / maximum values in your code that I have modified (maximum value that I inserted is arbitrary).

```
#include <Servo.h>
int pos = 0;

Servo myservo; # creating an instance myservo of Servo class

// Consult servo datasheet for the pulse width necessary to move servo's shaft to minimum (0 degrees) and maximum position (n degrees)
// attach function min and maximum values allow to fine tune servo positioning at 0 degrees and n degrees (90, 180, ...)
int servo_min = 544 ; # servo minimum pulse  width in microseconds, default = 544 microseconds
int servo_max = 2300 ; # servo maximum width, default = 2400 microseconds

// void setup() {myservo.attach(22);}
void setup() {myservo.attach(22, servo_min, servo_max);}

void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) {
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }

  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
    myservo.write(pos);
    delay(15);
  }

}
```

Comment: there is no problem of me pushing it to its limits, even if i make it move in the middle of it range, it after some time just stops listening to the code, and goes far right by itself without me telling it to do so. and then i have to remove the power from it and force it to some more normal position just for it to start listening again, and usually, it just goes far right again.

Comment: It could be a power supply problem to the servomotor and/or an electrical interference.
For that kind of servomotors like MG996R You should not use the power +5V from the Arduino board.
Also power section have to be adequate to the currents. Breadboard internal wiring is not recommended for such servomotors.
In the background the Arduino Servo library sends an impulse to the servomotor every 20 ms (50 Hz). Electrical disturbance or low voltage can affect microcontroller. 
That are wiring problems/hardware problems.
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/servo-moving-on-its-own/1015174

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with power as it has its own sufficient power supply